# Ajax call is returning error from action controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

on change of a dropdown value i am trying to populate other dropdown list value.

Here i have added my new action in routes.rb :

```
 resources :appointments do 
    collection do
      get :getdata
    end
  end
```

This is my js code :

```
 $("#appointment_department_id").change(function(){ 
//on change of department dropdown.
    $.ajax({
      url: "/appointment/getdata",
      type: "GET",
      data: {department_id: $(this).val()},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
       error: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }

     });
  });
```

here is my action in controller file :

```
   def getdata
     @dept_id = params[:department_id]
     department_name  = @dept_id 
      @all_doctors = User.all;  #will write my custom query later. 
  end
```

But on call to this action, it's returning error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/appointment/getdata?department_id=5"
```

(checked in firebug)

Comment: What kind of error exactly?

Comment: Hey what kind of a response you are expecting?

Comment: post complete details of ur problem, otherwise no one will be able to solve it. likewise, what type of error u r getting and what u r expecting in ajax response?

Comment: the error is in the routes, in the ajax request you are using 'appointment/getdata', but in routes you have defined appointments,

so use

Comment: to get more details about your problem, open firebug then click in the error "?etworkError: 404 Not Found....." to see what you get as response, you will see a lot of html + css in the top of response but don't care, scroll down until you find an indication of your error

Answer (score 1):

the error is in the ajax url, in the ajax request you are using 'appointment/getdata', but in routes you have defined appointments,

so use

```
$("#appointment_department_id").change(function(){ 
//on change of department dropdown.
    $.ajax({
      **url: "/appointments/getdata",**
      type: "GET",
      data: {department_id: $(this).val()},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
       error: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }

     });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out  missing 's'.
but it did n't fix my issue. :(
now error is:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3010/appointments/getdata?department_id=10"

Answer (score 1):

**Where's your [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) in your controller?**

If you're sending an Ajax request, you'll have to either define respond_to "JS" or "JSON" like this:

```
def getdata
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js 
    end
end
```

You could also do it like this:

```
Class Controller 
    respond_to :html,:js, :json

    def getdata
      respond_with(@custom_vars)
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks rich for this info, I learnt a lot from your post ! 
But in my case i fixed it by placing the resources :appointment section after following block of code. 

resources :appointments do 
    collection do
      get :getdata
    end
  end

now placed,
resources :appointments 

as if i declare my getdata after the default line then the ajax call was rendering the show action. I am not sure why ???
But by placing the position of action declaration in routes, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget "s" of "appointment" word in url: "/appointment/getdata", so try to add "s" like this :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/appointments/getdata",
...
...
```

Comment: That's already pointed by @kuldeep, you can check the next post. 
But on fixing this URL did not fix my issue.